# Sending (pushing) Soap WS messages trough biztalk at given time

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, jobs, biztalk

I would like to know if someone could provide example or a link on some tutorial which would show how to send messages using soap as a job (at given time) trough biztalk. I have expirience doing this with in java enviroment with JMS, but Im doing it for the first time in .net and its technologies.

What I need to do could be broken into steps.

1. Create WCF SOAP service that would have one method for sending collection of data from our system to a vendors system trough BizTalk.
2. Do this at given time - create a job(timer) that would do this once a day. What is the best way? Should I program this job by myself or is it common to use some windows scheduler on server?

Thanx a lot for any suggestions.

**Edit:** Concept of comunication: app1-client(here is the timing job)->sends data->biztalk-server(WS)->sends data ->app2-server(WS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically it make sense to have the system that owns the data also own the scheduling of sending out the data. For example, if the data is coming out of SQL Server, use SQL Server's built-in functionality for scheduling (SQL Jobs) as your trigger to kick off the whole process. Then, have the SQL Job dump the data to a file, in a folder monitored by a BizTalk receive location using the file adapter. BizTalk sucks in the file and a send port, which subscribes to the messages coming in from the receive port that pulled in the file, uses a WCF or SOAP adapter to send the data to your web service on the external server.

If you don't want to or can't do things that way, I have seen people use:

- The Scheduled Task Adapter on CodePlex (as @tomasr referenced)
- A Windows Scheduled Task (more difficult to manage, especially prior to Windows Server 2008)
- Third-party job scheduling software (particularly if already in use)

If the triggering mechanism does not have access to the data that needs to flow through BizTalk, BizTalk can certainly go and get the data (e.g., from SQL Server), before sending it to the server's web service. In that case the scheduled job could drop a file in the folder monitored by BizTalk with some content in it that BizTalk doesn't care about - just make sure that there is something in the file, because BizTalk likes to discard empty, 0 byte files.

BizTalk is not a job scheduler. So, though you can use something like the scheduled task adapter, BizTalk's sweet spot is really the transformation, routing, and/or business process orchestration of messages, along with a pluggable architecture (using adapters). Typically you want to let BizTalk handle all of those functions and use some other system (if available) for scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not sure what you're asking. Are you wanting to expose a WS *from* BizTalk to the other system, or call a WS exposed *by* the other system *from* BizTalk? The [BizTalk docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb246032%28v=BTS.10%29.aspx) should get you started in either one.
2. BizTalk doesn't have anything built-in for scheduling. However, the most common workaround for this is to use the BizTalk Scheduled Task Adapter, which you can get from its [codeplex site](http://biztalkscheduledtask.codeplex.com/).
3. Not sure what you mean by this. Can you clarify?

Comment: Okey let me try again 1. I want my application to push data at given time once a day (using soap ws) trough biztalk to other aplication. 2. What is the best practice for time scheduling. I need to trigger update I described above(sending data from my app to other app). Biztalk will be pasive in this role just recieving data from my web service and forwarding them to target app. 3. This mechanizm from point two will also work the other way around. The other app will trigger update expose its soap service to biztalk and I want to consume this data at the other end.

Comment: It depends on what you want; really. Will there be any other processing besides just calling the service and pushing the response to another system? Will you need to transform or map messages between the systems? If not, it could be BizTalk is overkill for the task at hand.

Comment: As for the rest, seems indeed that the BizTalk Scheduled Task Adapter might be your best bet here, if you choose to go ahead with BizTalk.