# BizTalk WCF Service Polling

Tags: wcf, web-services, biztalk, polling, biztalk-2010

I need to perform polling on a WCF service inside BizTalk. The workflow would be as follows:

1. Pool the service (a string is returned, that should be mapped to a schema)
2. If there's no message available (exception raised/404/empty string/whatever is easier), go to 5
3. Convert the string into the proper schema, process and forward the message
4. Go back to 1
5. Wait for 5 minutes and go back to 1

I've used 'Consume WCF Service' to generate the ports and schemas. But now i cannot find a way to orchestrate this workflow. Here are some questions to which I'm unable to find answers:

- How can create a scheduled check to see if there's data available in the web service call?
- How can I cast the XML string from the request into a known schema?
- Imagine that I would like the message to be casted into a different schema depending on a property from the received XML, how should I do this?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: BizTalk can't do this out of the box AFAIK (it can poll Files,  SQL or Message Queues, but not Web Services). There's a bunch of hacks to trigger an orch in BizTalk which calls your webservice - e.g. http://geekswithblogs.net/BizTalkUnleashed/archive/2011/07/11/restful-service-polling-biztalk-receive-location.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BizTalk is not a job scheduler, but this sort of workflow does comes up a lot when organizations already use BizTalk. Your best bet is to find a reliable (and resilient, monitored, logged, etc.) means of triggering the process, telling BizTalk when it is time to call the WCF service.

I answered another question about BizTalk scheduling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5435123/241754). From that answer, you may be able to use one of these options for scheduling:

- [The Scheduled Task Adapter on CodePlex](http://biztalkscheduledtask.codeplex.com/) - I would only use this if you cannot use another method of triggering your scheduled workflow
- A Windows Scheduled Task (more difficult to manage, especially prior to Windows Server 2008; you can user [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx#EBAA) to write a file or to a message queue that BizTalk sucks in to kick off its process)
- Third-party job scheduling software (particularly if already in use; even [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx) can do [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/code/WorkingWithFiles/spWriteStringTofile.txt) for you)